# iOS - How to handle the case where a user enables push notifications while app is still running?

Tags: ios, push-notification

When my application starts, I register for push notifications. If the user decides to deny them, I never get a device token. If they later, while the app is still running, enable notifications, how can I detect that and register for push notificatoins so I can get my device token? Do I just have to wait for them to restart the app? Or is it possible to be notified when the user enables notifications while my app is still running?

Thanks!

Comment: User has to put your app in background so he/she can use Settings app to enable the permission.  As such, you can use applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationDidEnterBackground to register.

Comment: Oh, duh! That's a good answer. Had you submitted that as an answer, I would have marked that as the accepted answer. However, under the circumstances, all I can do is upvote your comment. So, upvoted! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with:

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications(){
   //......
}
```

Comment: Doesn't actually answer my question, but still useful. :) Thanks!